# Correct Term for describing "diamond" subgraphs in a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: graphs, terminology, graph-traversal, dag

I am trying to research handling a specific type of possible subgraph in directed acyclic graphs.

However, I am struggling to find the correct term to use.
If we consider the subgraph S to be in a DAG G. Where S is made up of 2 paths, starting at a common node and ending at a common node. Thus forming a "diamond" shape when arranged the starting node to the ending node.

For example:

[image: simple diamond subgraph]

So, what would be the correct term for describing subgraphs that fit this condition when describing the graph? Is there even such a term, let alone existing literature?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the two paths limited to a single intermediate node ?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone will know what you mean by "diamond", in computer science, if you define it up front. See, for example: [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

I don't think there is a standard name for this structure. But also, the term "diamond" doesn't always refer to this, even in mathematical objects that can be represented as directed acyclic graphs.

For example, I have seen the lattice $\mathcal{M}_3$ referred to as "the diamond", for obvious reasons when you look at its Hasse diagram.

[image: Hasse diagram of M3]

If it has a domain-specific interpretation, of course, then you should use that (e.g. if it's a "unique implication point" in clause learning).

Comment: In undirected graphs, diamond is typically $K_4-e$.